# mailto links in iPhone are adding plus signs instead of spaces

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, mailto

I have a web app that I'm building right now that needs to use a mailto: link for the tell-a-friend portion. The message body was too long for a URL, so I had it in a hidden form and am sending the form via jQuery.

Everything is working brilliantly, except that it is adding + signs where the spaces should go. I've tried unescaping, replacing "+" with spaces, but as soon as it gets to "mailto_form.submit();", the + signs get added to the subject and body.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```js
<form id="mailto_form" action="mailto:" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;height:1px;width:1px;" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="{$tellafriend_subject|replace:'"':'&quot;'}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Body" value="{$tellafriend_body|replace:'"':'&quot;'}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

$(".email_link").click(function(e) {
    var mailto_form = $("#mailto_form");

    var val = $("input[name=Subject]", mailto_form).val();
    val = val.replace("[[[NAME]]]", firstname);
    $("input[name=Subject]", mailto_form).val(val);

    var val = $("input[name=Body]", mailto_form).val();
    val = val.replace("[[[NAME]]]", firstname + " " + lastname);
    $("input[name=Body]", mailto_form).val(val);

    mailto_form.submit();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I've fixed this by replacing spaces with &nbsp;

Comment: You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Use `%20`

Seems to be an issue of the iOS mail client. In lieu of `+`, you can URL-encode a space as `%20`. I just ran into the issue and %20 is my solution to it.