# Avoid space change into plus sign in iPhone from mailto link

Tags: php

I have a php code that renders a `mailto:` link

```
echo "<a href='mailto:?'". http_build_query([
   'subject' => 'this is a subject',
   'body' => 'this is a body',
])."'>Link</a>";
```

In my desktop browser, when I clicked the link the browser goes to GMail and the mail body is rendered nicely.

But when I use my iPhone, the compose app shows "+" instead of spaces.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Rewrite the compose app. Or tell Apple to.

Comment: So there is really no workaround for this?

Comment: Don't URL encode your strings (don't use `http_build_query()`) - that way your spaces will become %20 instead, which I presume Apple handles, and the end result will be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto links in iPhone are adding plus signs instead of spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539399/mailto-links-in-iphone-are-adding-plus-signs-instead-of-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

This is standard URI code. Spaces are expected to be transformed to something else than a space. The most common character is the '+', some people prefer to use %20.

When you decode a URI, it automatically replaces the '+' back to spaces. So your code is probably missing that one call...

You probably want to look at this function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

---

According to scrowler comment, try to put %20 instead of spaces to see what happens:

```
echo "<a href='mailto:?'". http_build_query([
   'subject' => 'this%20is%20a%20subject',
   'body' => 'this%20is%20a%20body',
])."'>Link</a>";
```

Comment: It's the iPhone app that isn't decoding the string - should we ask Apple to add this in?

Comment: Oh... so by changing the code with %20 instead of spaces, it may just all work as expected...

Comment: `echo '<a href="mailto:?subject=this is a subject&body=this is a body">Link</a>` (literally) is actually what I suggested, the browser automatically encodes spaces as %20.

Comment: scrowler, well... maybe you could write your own answer 8-) But I see what you mean now, `http_build_query()` would be what adds the `+`. And with `%20`, it may change it to `%2520`...

Comment: @PetraBarus, do you understand what scrowler is proposing? His solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

For building the mailto http query string to be compatible with Apple mail and *not* show spaces as `+` plus signs you need to use the `encoding_type` param in the [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function and set it to constant `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` so that spaces are encoded with the `%20` instead of `+`.

Build the mailto query string:

```
$mailToParams = http_build_query(
    [
        'subject' => "The Subject!",
        'body' => "Here's the body of the message. \n\nAdd in a couple new lines."
    ],
    null,
    '&',
    PHP_QUERY_RFC3986
);
```

Add it to your link:

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com?<?php echo $mailToParams; ?>">Mail Me</a>
```